# Attempting to produce sales from 2013 and Sales from 2012 in two different columns using sub queries

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to produce a query result, that allows for the sales to appear in two columns. One column for 2012 and one for 2013. I am able to yield the results I am lookingn for but it is producing them in three columns. One with two nulls, one with a null in 2012, and one in 2013.

I have tried adding a group by in SQL query, and also moving the whole query to the from statement, but I am rather new to sub queries.

```
select distinct 
ResellerName, 
(Select Sum(Salesamount) where Year(Orderdate) = 2012) as "2012 sales" , (Select Sum(Salesamount) where Year(Orderdate) = 2013) as "2013 sales" 
from [dbo].[DimReseller] as R, [dbo].[FactResellerSales] as S
where R.ResellerKey = s.resellerkey 
group by ResellerName, Year(OrderDate)
```

Expected Results: [ResellerName], [2012 Sales], [2013 Sales] in one column
Actual results: Three Columns are produced where they each have a null.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a simple conditional aggregation (with proper explicit join syntax) -

```
SELECT ResellerName
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Year(Orderdate) = 2012 THEN Salesamount END) as "2012 sales"
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Year(Orderdate) = 2013 THEN Salesamount END) as "2013 sales"
FROM [dbo].[DimReseller] as R
JOIN [dbo].[FactResellerSales] as S ON R.ResellerKey = s.resellerkey
GROUP BY ResellerName
```